# increase query limitations at overpass api

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

I have an application with leaflet and overpass.api. I use [this](https://github.com/GuillaumeAmat/leaflet-overpass-layer) overpass-layer plugin to query to OSM data.
My problem ist, when i query to0 often to overpass.api i get an Too Many request error after 2 queries.

[overpass-api status](http://overpass-api.de/api/status) shows me that there is a limitation. There is 1 available slot, and after a query it blocks my IP for a time period (30sec-3min). 
Why is my IP banned already after 1 query?

I wanted to make an application to search with OSM tags and receive data from OSM database. My application works , but it is not possible to query often.

Comment: Duplicate post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/52333/how-to-query-more-than-once-every-2-3min-to-overpassapi

Comment: is this not allowed? its a different site

Comment: Posting the same question simultaneously on multiple sites just wastes everyones time. That's why most people won't bother to answer your question anymore.

Comment: its like parallel computing